# How can I perform remove to cart and update cart without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a simple code to add items to cart, when a user removes items to cart the page refreshes and that makes it scroll back to the top. updating quantity also does the same. I belive i can have these functions work without page refresh but i dont know how to execute this. here is my cart code

```
<?php 
session_start();

// check if the delete_id is passed via the URL
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete_id'];
    // search for the product to delete
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $product) {
        if($product['id'] === $delete_id) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        }
    }
}

// check if the update_id and quantity are passed via the URL
if(isset($_GET['update_id']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
    $update_id = (int)$_GET['update_id'];
    $quantity = (int)$_GET['quantity'];
    // search for the product to update
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $product) {
        if($product['id'] === $update_id) {
            if(isset($product['quantity'])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Header menu with logo, about us, and cart menu -->
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <div id="test">
    <a href="test.php">products Page</a>
    </div>
    <div id="about-us">About Us</div>
    <div id="cart-menu">      
      <a href="cart.php">Cart (<?=count($_SESSION['cart'])?>)</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Cart list -->
  <div id="cart-list">
    <?php 
    if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        echo '<p>Your cart is empty</p>';
    } else {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
            echo $product['name']. " <br>";
            echo '<button type="button" onclick="decrementQuantity('.$product['id'].')">-</button>';
            echo '<span id="product-'.$product['id'].'-quantity">'.(isset($product['quantity']) ? $product['quantity'] : 1).'</span>';
            echo '<button type="button" onclick="incrementQuantity('.$product['id'].')">+</button>';            
            $subtotal = $product['price'] * (isset($product['quantity']) ? $product['quantity'] : 1);
            echo '<p>Subtotal: $<span id="product-'.$product['id'].'-subtotal">'.number_format($subtotal,2).'</span></p>';
            $total += $subtotal;
            echo '<p><button type="button" onclick="removeFromCart('.$product['id'].')">Remove Item from Cart</button></p>';
            echo '<hr>';
            }
            echo '<p>Total: $<span id="total">'.number_format($total,2).'</span></p>';
            }
            ?>
          </div>
          <script>
          function incrementQuantity(id) {
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML);
            var newQuantity = currentQuantity + 1;
            updateQuantity(id, newQuantity);
          }
          function decrementQuantity(id) {
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML);
            if(currentQuantity > 1) {
                var newQuantity = currentQuantity - 1;
                updateQuantity(id, newQuantity);
            }
          }
          function updateQuantity(id, value) {
            var url = "cart.php?update_id=" + id + "&quantity=" + value;
            // Change the displayed quantity
            document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML = value;
            // Update the subtotal
            var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-subtotal').innerHTML) / parseInt(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML);
            document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-subtotal').innerHTML = price * value;
            updateTotal();
            window.location.href = url;
          }
          function removeFromCart(id) {
            var url = "cart.php?delete_id=" + id;
            window.location.href = url;
          }
          function updateTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            var subtotals = document.getElementsByClassName('product-subtotal');
            for (var i = 0; i < subtotals.length; i++) {
                total += parseFloat(subtotals[i].innerHTML);
            }
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
          }
          </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

what i have read is i should add event listeners to the buttons and use $.ajax() method... I am not so good in coding therefore i cant implement this so i dont even know if it will work

Comment: You have already tagged the question with the correct solution and mentioned it in your question, use Ajax. There are many guides/tutorials out there that should get you started with it. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, come back, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried and explain the issue in detail (with any debugging info) and we can help from there. We're glad to help with specific issues, but we're not here to write all the code for you (which an answer here would require us to)

Comment: Good thing to know is that `$.ajax()` isn't a native JavaScript method, it's a jQuery method (which is a third party JavaScript library). If you're not already using jQuery, then I would recommend you to read about the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead, which is native in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start();
// check if the delete_id is passed via the URL
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete_id'];
    // search for the product to delete
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $product) {
        if($product['id'] === $delete_id) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            echo "success";die;
        }
    }
}

// check if the update_id and quantity are passed via the URL
if(isset($_GET['update_id']) && isset($_GET['quantity'])) {
    $update_id = (int)$_GET['update_id'];
    $quantity = (int)$_GET['quantity'];
    // search for the product to update
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $product) {
        if($product['id'] === $update_id) {
            if(isset($product['quantity'])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = 1;
            }
            echo "success";die;
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cart</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        <div id="test">
            <a href="test.php">products Page</a>
        </div>
        <div id="about-us">About Us</div>
        <div id="cart-menu">      
            <a href="cart.php">Cart (<?=count($_SESSION['cart'])?>)</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Cart list -->
    <div id="cart-list">
        <?php 
        if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            echo '<p>Your cart is empty</p>';
        } else {
            $total = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
                echo "<div class='product product-".$product['id']."'>";
                echo $product['name']. " <br>";
                echo '<input type="hidden" id="product-'.$product['id'].'-price" value="'.$product['price'].'">';
                echo '<button type="button" onclick="decrementQuantity('.$product['id'].')">-</button>';
                echo '<span id="product-'.$product['id'].'-quantity">'.(isset($product['quantity']) ? $product['quantity'] : 1).'</span>';
                echo '<button type="button" onclick="incrementQuantity('.$product['id'].')">+</button>';            
                $subtotal = $product['price'] * (isset($product['quantity']) ? $product['quantity'] : 1);
                echo '<p>Subtotal: $<span id="product-'.$product['id'].'-subtotal" class="subtotals">'.number_format($subtotal,2).'</span></p>';
                $total += $subtotal;
                echo '<p><button type="button" onclick="removeFromCart('.$product['id'].')">Remove Item from Cart</button></p>';
                echo '<hr></div>';
            }
            echo '<p>Total: $<span id="total">'.number_format($total,2).'</span></p>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        function incrementQuantity(id) {
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML);
            var newQuantity = currentQuantity + 1;
            updateQuantity(id, newQuantity);
        }
        function decrementQuantity(id) {
            var currentQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('product-' + id + '-quantity').innerHTML);
            if(currentQuantity > 1) {
                var newQuantity = currentQuantity - 1;
                updateQuantity(id, newQuantity);
            }
        }
        function updateQuantity(id, value) {
            var $proC = $('.product.product-' + id );
            var product_price = $('#product-'+id+'-price').val();
            
            $proC.find('button').attr("disabled","disabled");
            var url = "cart.php?update_id=" + id + "&quantity=" + value;
            
            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'GET',
                success:function(response){
                    $proC.find('button').removeAttr("disabled");
                    if($.trim(response) == 'success'){
                        document.getElementById('product-'+id+'-quantity').innerHTML = value;
                        document.getElementById('product-'+id+'-subtotal').innerHTML = product_price * value;
                    }else{
                        alert("Something went wrong.try again..");
                    }
                    updateTotal();
                },
                error:function(err){
                    $proC.find('button').removeAttr("disabled");
                    alert(err);
                }
            })
        }
        function removeFromCart(id) {
            var url = "cart.php?delete_id=" + id;
            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:'GET',
                success:function(response){
                    if($.trim(response) == 'success'){
                        $('.product.product-'+id).remove();
                        alert("Product removed.");
                    }else{
                        alert("Something went wrong.try again..");
                    }
                },
                error:function(err){
                    alert(err);
                }
            })
        }
        function updateTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            var subtotals = document.getElementsByClassName('subtotals');
            for (var i = 0; i < subtotals.length; i++) {
                total += parseFloat(subtotals[i].innerHTML);
            }
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Arun Chouhan... this is what I needed. Just one thing I'm realizing removing items from the cart now the number of items in the cart is not updated until I refresh the page. such that if i remove all items the cart total will still remain as when there were items in the cart...after refresh is when the correct total is displayed

Comment: In `removeFromCart()` function call the `updateTotal()` function.

Comment: perfect it's working as I wanted it.  just a side question, when updating the quantity of an item in the cart, both the subtotal and cart total lose the number_format.. . how do i correct that.

Comment: Use toFixed() function,

`price_variable.toFixed(2);`